# Multithreaded queue manager

Tags: javascript, queue

I've written a simple multithreaded queue manager in JavaScript which will be seeing some pretty heavy usage at a later point in the project I'm working on. I think it's pretty solid, but I wouldn't mind hearing some other opinions on it. Any potential problems?

For convenience, here's a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/dujud/6/edit) of the queue.

```
function Queue(callback, threads, queue) {
    var q = this;

    // variables
    this.queue = queue || [];
    this.callback = callback;
    this.threads = threads || 1;

    // add element to the queue to be checked
    this.add = function (elem) {
        this.queue.push(elem);
    };

    // this should be called when the execute function has finished
    this.continue = function (delay) {
        if (!delay) {
            // if there's no delay, just call the function immediately
            if (!this.queue.length) {
                return;
            }

            this.callback.call(this, this.queue.shift());
        } else {
            // otherwise, wait until later to call the function
            setTimeout(function () {
                // anything left in the queue?
                if (!q.queue.length) {
                    return;
                }

                q.callback.call(q, q.queue.shift());
            }, delay);
        }
    };

    // begin iterating through the queue
    this.begin = function () {
        var i = this.threads;
        while (i--) {
            this.continue();
        }
    };
}
```

Example usage:

```
// create object
var q = new Queue();

// specify maximum threads
q.threads = 10;

// and a callback
q.callback = function (item) {
  // do stuff with item
  console.log(item);

  // only call this when this function has finished
  // number is the delay in ms to wait before continuing
  this.continue(1000);
};

// add some items to the queue
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    q.add(i);
}

// begin working through the queue
q.begin();
```

Comment: IIRC, JS isn't a multi-threaded langu
age

Comment: @TopinFrassi Correct, JS is strictly single-threaded. The exception is if you explicitly use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) - however this code doesn't seem to make use of that.

Comment: Yep, JS is definitely single-threaded. This could theoretically be used in node.js for concurrent operations though (i.e. processing the next item while waiting for some async i/o to complete).

Comment: JS can simulate multiple threads via `setTimeout` reasonably enough to warrant the title of this question.

Comment: Suggesting you use polyfills instead https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-workers